# Кэширование страниц drupal и hook_init

Tags: php, drupal, кэширование

Столкнулся с проблемой кэширования в Drupal 7.  Я использую модуль `Admin Security` который при за ходе на страницу авторизации, запускает проверку текущего ip со списком ip который хранится в БД (белый список адресов). И если ip зашедшего на страницу авторизации отличается со списком адресов nо страница авторизации пользователю не показывается (возвращает 403). В php все просто запускается функция `admin_security_init()` в которой происходят все проверки. 
Почитав по просторам интернета понятно что хук `init`  запускается если страница `не кэширована`. И правильно, запустив модуль и полный сброс кэша модуль какое-то время работает пока страница не закэшируется. 
Сам модуль:

```
function admin_security_init() {

  if (variable_get('admin_security_enabled', 0)) {
    if (_admin_security_parseurl()) {
      module_load_include('inc', 'admin_security', 'inc/admin_security_ip_check');
      $current_ip = ip_address();
      if ($current_ip != '127.0.0.1') {
        $allowed = FALSE;
        $allowed_ips = variable_get('admin_security_ips');
        if (isset($allowed_ips) && is_array($allowed_ips)) {
          $allowed = _admin_security_ip_is_allowed($current_ip, $allowed_ips);
        }
        elseif (class_exists('Database', FALSE)) {
          $allowed = _admin_security_ip_is_allowed($current_ip);
        }
        // Deny access if an allowed IP address is not available.
        if (!$allowed) {
          watchdog('admin_security', 'An admin page request from IP @ip was blocked.', array('@ip' => $current_ip));
          header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
          header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
          echo "<p>Access denied! Доступ закрыт!</p>
          <p>This page is available only by ip. Данная страница доступна только по ip</p>
           <p>" . check_plain(ip_address()) . " has been banned from site administration. " . check_plain(ip_address()) . " был заблокирован администратором сайта. </p> ";
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Что я делал:

1. Кто-то писал, что можно попробовать отключить кэш таким методо

   `function admin_security_boot(){
         if( !empty( $_SESSION['cart_items'] ) ){ 
           $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = false; 
         }
       }`

Не получилось. Через минут 10-15 модуль перестает работать

2. Установил модуль `Cache exclusions` который исключает из кэширования нужные страницы. Опять не пошло.
3. Отключал в самом в друпале `admin/config/development/performance` кэширование полностью.

Итог модуль какое-то время работает, потом перестает. Помогает полный сброс кэша.
Можно конечно попробовать внедрить полный сброс кэша на все внутренние страницы, но это такой себе выход честно говоря. Наверное воспользуюсь им если уже ничего не поможет и никто не поможет:)

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит утяжелять сайт таким модулем! в Drupal и прочих cms, любой модуль - это нагрузка на сервер.
Все это решается проще и надежнее средствами самого сервера.
Для апача пишем в .httacces

```
<Directory /user/login>
Order deny,allow
deny from all
# Список IP через пробел, с которых доступ разрешен
Allow from 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.3 //примеры ip
```

для nginx

```
location /user/login {    
# блокируем все    
deny    all;    
# кроме    
allow   192.168.2.5 192.168.2.5;    
}
```

путь /user/login - стандартный в drupal на страницу логина, точнее `/?q=user` - пробуйте и этот путь.

Comment: Для httacces пробовал возвращает 500 Internal Server Error. И на сколько я знаю первый вариант доступен если такая директория существует явно. А у друпала этот путь генерится.

Comment: исправил путь на более конкретный... у меня 8 Drupal-е и nginx работает

Comment: для httaccess там ошибка 500 опять

Comment: логи апача в студию...